# Pentaho Data Integration Transformation Executor

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

Without going too much into our final product, I have a bunch of transformations that are strung together via Transformation Executor steps at the end.  Transformation 1 has a Transformation Executor step at the end that executes Transformation 2.

I now have the need to build transformations that handle more than one input stream (e.g. utilize an Append Streams step under the covers).  While it's easy enough to have each input transformation execute the same transformation during its Transformation Executor step, I'm afraid it won't do the right thing unless I specify which input stream within the Transformation Executor step the current stream needs to be mapped to. Unfortunately, Pentaho's documentation is very weak (i.e. nonexistent) on this topic.

Is there a way to specify that?

If I'm way off and this really isn't a concern, please clarify that.

Thanks in advance as always for any help you can give me!!

Comment: Let me try and understand better, what you require is that the input stream on KTR 1, executes more than once, for different bases so to speak is that it ? Like an SQL query that can be run on multiple DB's, and KTR 2 will just transform this data, no matter where it comes from ? Is that correct ?

Comment: I can cover the case you outline.  What I actually have is KTR 1 and KTR 2 generating data and I need them to both be inputs into KTR 3, which transforms both streams.  Is there a way to map KTR 1 to one input into KTR 3 and map KTR 2 into the other?

Comment: If KTR 1 and 2 only generate data, or have very few steps, why segregate them into 2 KTR's ? If it is just 2 inputs, place them all on a single KTR and join them there. If you could share an image perhaps, or a sample KJB/KTR that would help a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure I can show you sample code without violating some sort of privacy agreement with my company.  Essentially, KTR1 and KTR2 re building blocks.  Sometimes we'll need to only connect the output of KTR1 to the input of some other step.  Sometimes it will only be KTR2.  Sometimes we'll want to combine the input sources and connect the combined output into another step.  Sometimes we'll want to connect the two outputs into two separate inputs in a third step (e.g. something doing a Merge Sort under the covers).  It's the last one that might spell out the problem best.